# Intellij Idea 13.1.4 JavaFX Packager: build failed

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I try to compile my javafx project (i use Intellij Idea 13.1.4 and (Java 8))

But when i try to run/build project, i get following errors:

(Intellij idea Output)

```
Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
/home/xxx/.IntelliJIdea13/system/compile-server/_temp_/
build3225267923367377518.xml:30: Element type "fx:info" 
must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Total time: 0 seconds
```

---

```
Error:Java FX Packager: Buildfile: /home/xxx/.IntelliJIdea13/system/
compile-server/_temp_/build3225267923367377518.xml
```

---

```
Error:Java FX Packager: fx:deploy task has failed.
```

I already done search any solution, but nothing found...

Answer (score -1):

I've just got this same error with IntelliJ 14.0.3. After a bit of trial and error, I determined the cause to be double-quotation `"` marks in `File->Project Structure->Artifacts->Java FX`.

Removing the `"` from there fixed the issue for me.

It seems that the supplied data on that tab is blindly inputted into the auto-generated build.xml file. So, whatever you can usually add to an XML attribute value is valid. You can use single-quotation `'` mark in this case.

Comment: Which field do you mean int Java FX tab?